# Strophe MUC example

Tags: xmpp, strophe

Does anyone have an example code for a join,changenick, ...etc functions calls in  Strophe muc extension ?

I tried to do this myself not sure how do i call the extensions functions, and add the plugin to the js,  is it adding

Comment: Does anyone have an example code for a join,changenick, ...etc functions calls in  Strophe muc extension ? 

I tried to do this myself not sure how do i call the extensions functions, and add the plugin to the js,  is it adding 
    
<script src='plugin/muc/strophe.muc.js'></script>

enough and then can i call MUC functions like this 

changeNick(roomid,nickname);

is there some init functions that i need to run ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Candy is a full blown MUC client based on Strophe. The code is excellent and easy to read.
I suggest to download it and study the code:
http://candy-chat.github.com/candy/

Alex

Answer (score 8):

You need to include the strophe.muc.js in our html file and after you established a Strophe connection, you can call the muc methods with conn.muc.foobarMethod() where conn is the established Strophe connection and foobarMethod is the method you'd like to call.

Instead of trying to build everything on your own (and from your question I assume that you don't have the relevant know-how), try an already built js xmpp client like [Candy](http://candy-chat.github.com/candy) which is also built upon Strophe.js.